# Darsa Sly Slider - Horizontal

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am looking to use the sly slider. I am trying to particularly using the horizontal slider. The link to the slider is as [here](http://darsa.in/sly/examples/horizontal.html).

I am trying to use the forced centered slider. But not able to get any help from documentation or anywhere else. If somebody can provide me a good example on how can I use it. That will be great.

Comment: I have uploaded my files on the following url:
http://wellspringinfotech.com/landing_page/sly-master/new.html

Comment: The slider is still not working on it. I don't get the issue. Can you look to it?

Comment: You seem to have a javascript dependency error: "Uncaught TypeError: a.easing[rb.easing] is not a function". Have you tried using the non-compressed version of Sly? Maybe his min.js version is unstable

Comment: Yes, I am looking to this. But thats the one available on their webiste.

Comment: Also, I am not able to see any other similar to what I need. Do you have any idea what can I use?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, but if you visit the project's github, you can download the non-compressed file, here, just right-click/save as: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/darsain/sly/master/dist/sly.js

Comment: if the problem persist, try adding the jquery Easing file (right after the jquery file): https://plugins.jquery.com/jquery.easing/

Comment: changed the file. But still getting same issue.:(

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so I got it working. I only needed to add the Jquery Easing file and everything worked as expected.

HTML:

```
<body>
//BODY CONTENT

//Scripts files
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/sly.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/horizantal.js"></script>
</body>
```

Add this file to your project (or use the CDN): [Jquery Easing](https://plugins.jquery.com/jquery.easing/)

[JSFIDDLE WORKING EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/IndieRok/aqyhbxub/)